# document.cookie returns empty string

Tags: javascript

I tried entering

```
 javascript:alert(document.cookie)
```

in the browser, and it returned the cookies. But when I tried to do the same via JS code, i.e, made an html page which on load stored document.cookie in a var and then displayed it in console, it returned an empty string.

Please help.

Comment: Different page, different cookies? Why did you expect any to be set?

Comment: Oh! So when I enter that query in the url bar of the browser, then it displays the global cookies, right? Is there any way to see the global cookies other than entering the JS command in the url bar?

Comment: What's a "global" cookie? A [cookie is always bound to a domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie). When you use the `javascript:` pseudo protocol, the js will be executed in the currently loaded page.

Comment: The reason why I asked the question was due to the following [site](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp) I was learning about cookies. and on this site, they have a button that says display all cookies. So I got confused, and I thought that maybe there's some way to see all the cookies stored. Anyway thanks for your reply. Things have become clear :)

Comment: A way to inspect all the cookies is only via your browser tools. In most devtools, you can see all cookies (from a few domains) relevant for the current site